# How to infer types of the transformed values of an object

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm struggling with how to type a function which transform an object by iterating over each of the properties of an object and transforming those individually.

```
const x = {a: 1, b: 'hello'};
const y = {c: 1, d: true};

function transform<T extends Object>(src:T): {[k in keyof T]: any[]} {
    return Object.keys(src).reduce((acc, key) => ({...acc, [key]: [src]}), {}) as any;
}

// ideally typed {a: number[], b: string[]}
// actually typed {a: any[], b: any[]}
const xPrime = transform(x); 

// ideally typed {c: number[], d: boolean[]}
// actually typed {c: any[], d: any[]}
const yPrime = transform(y);
```

In this case I'm wrapping them in Arrays - but I expect the solution will help me resolve a more involved problem for other container types.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `any[]` by `T[k][]`:

```js
function transform<T extends Object>(src:T): {[k in keyof T]: T[k][]} {
    throw Error('unimplemented'); // Your implementation is weird
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQzAZ2HFBbAHgBVEBTADylLABNNEB5AIwCtToA+ACkxQgC4iASn6IA3gG0A1ohhIppAJ5xgiIgF1RRaeonqAvuICwAKETnkACxRwA7ogCiKGyi4BycDDwAHADak8aioaNyEAblN9U1MIBEwoRHJEAF5xNFEARgAaRCZRN0tSX184N30Ik1isBPIABRQvUhTkdCwcfC5ycJi4hMVmsQFEbMQaUVQQUnKe6sRFesbm1AxsXDwuRXDEUyA)

Comment: You can create a short link to the playground here: https://tsplay-dev.now.sh/

Comment: Fabulous - much simpler than I expected!